# Pointing local machine to itself through internet

Tags: windows-xp, service, static-ip

I'm very inexperienced with networking, so bear with me.

I'm trying to connect to a windows service using soapclient in php, but I'm getting this error..  I believe the machine running the service is serving its local name as the source.

`Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://rimage1:55555/RmJobService.svc?xsd=xsd2) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/blah.php on line 8`

I've set up a static ip for this system and can access port 80 fine. It looks like I need to change the computer name in the ESDL to its IP, but if i try to access the machine's ip from itself, the request times out.

What would I need to do in order for the machine to find itself (rimage1) through the static ip?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like your client is unable to resolve rimage1. You should use the public(static) IP of the server and see if that takes care of it.
 You say it times out when you try to access its IP from itself - if you are trying to access its public IP, your firewall probably isn't allowing the traffic to pass from the server back to the server. Try using the IP as you thought and accessing it externally.

Comment: it seems like that to me, soapclient is trying to load the wsdl from http://rimage1... i need to somehow alter this so that the soapclient tries to access it from the public ip, but the computer can't talk to itself through the public ip

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the hosts file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, and point rimage1 to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to configure reverse NAT, if your router supports it, I am assuming you are trying to access the server from the server? If this is true reverse NAT may be your problem